# Jmeter JMS publisher configuration for websphere JMS queue

Tags: queue, jms, websphere, jmeter, publisher

I am now using Jmeter to test the JMS queue on websphere, for the test, I created following stuff on websphere console.

1.MyBus for Bus.
  2.MyDestination for Bus destination(Type is queue).
  3.MyConf connection factory.
  4.NyQueue has queue name MyDestinaion.

And here is my Jmeter test plan, I used JMS  Publisher  (Sorry, I can not upload the image, I don't know why, but you can imagine the pic, I think)

I also copied all the jar files from {Websphere_Home}/runtimes to {Jmeter_home}/lib

When I press start, Nothing happened, and here is the Jmeter log.

```
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7\bin\user.properties 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7\bin\system.properties 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2012 The Apache Software Foundation 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.7 r1342410 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_25 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=x86 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=GBK 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7\bin 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7\bin 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 9.119.102.62 Name: ADMINIB-5S47NH6 FullName: ADMINIB-5S47NH6.cn.ibm.com 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2015/07/10 14:18:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2015/07/10 14:18:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Reuse SSL session context on subsequent iterations: true 
2015/07/10 14:18:37 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui 
2015/07/10 14:18:37 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/07/10 14:18:37 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/07/10 14:18:37 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/07/10 14:18:37 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.7\bin' 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\MyTestPlan.jmx 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop' 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1332608 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.3 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2015/07/10 14:18:44 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop' 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Router Group. 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All threads have been started 
2015/07/10 14:18:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Router Group 1-1 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Router Group 1-1 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread Router Group 1-1 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory: InitialContextFactory.close() called and Context instances cleaned up 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2015/07/10 14:18:48 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host null
```

And message is not sent out, anyone knows the reason?

Comment: You didn't show you test plan

Comment: Name:JMS Point-to-Point
QueueConnection Factory: jms/MyQueueConF
JNDI Name Request queu: jms/MyQueue
Content: Text
Initial Context Factory: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
Provider URL: corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809